# Is there someway to update target branch automatically in merge procedure ?

Tags: tfs

In a merge operation, the target branch is not update automatically. We have to get last version manually. 
Is there a configuration in someplace of VS or TFS Server to automatically get last version of target branch before when a merge operation is triggered ?

Comment: There is a source control option in visual studio to always get altest before checking a file out - would this help?

Comment: Unfortunately, flagging this option does not make effect to merge operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this option does not exist.  If this is something you are passionate about then I would suggest voting for it on our UserVoice site.  We use feedback here to help prioritize our backlog.

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server

Comment: Having had to deal with the fallout of a merge from Main to a dev branch this morning, where the dev didn't have the latest of main. I'll be voting for this. Ensure that both the source and the target are at latest before performing the merge.

Comment: We are dealing with this kind of problem every day, a lot of developers are missing to get last version of main before a merge. I have started to create a VS Addin to replace the Default Merge Window with option to get last version of target before merge.